# How I Can Upload A php script in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

hello
Actually i am new to Google App Engine, i don't know how i can upload a php script in Google App Engine, any help thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done it myself but seems that you can have PHP run under GAE's Java runtime environment:

http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/

Have a look at that blog post and follow the steps there. It also has an example appspot app that seems to be working fine.

Comment: That is indeed possible using Quercus. I had forgotten about that. Another good blog entry about this is here: http://www.hm2k.com/posts/getting-started-with-quercus-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine only supports Python and Java scripts, they don't host PHP ones.

PHP support is currently the  [most upvoted feature request.](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log)

---

There is [an unofficial way](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/) to run PHP scripts on GAE. They seem to compile PHP scripts into Java classes which seems to result in decent performance (I haven't tried it yet, though).

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine currently only has Python and Java as the supported languages, so a PHP script would not work.

You're not the only person wanting it, as it is the most requested feature on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log). But that doesn't mean you will see it any time soon I think, as Google has not announced any upcoming support for it.